# Databases or schemas for an application on Postgres with many tables

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

I'm in the process of rolling out a new feature on my webapp that will ultimately result in users having the ability to create dynamic tables in the database. Over time I expect that this may result in thousands, or tens of thousands of tables being created.

I understand that [postgres doesn't have explicit limits](http://www.postgresql.org/about/) on the number of tables in the database, however that performance might degrade if that number gets too large. In order to mitigate this I'm thinking of breaking up the underlying storage into either different databases or different [schemas](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ddl-schemas.html). My main question is: is one of those choices choices better than the other? If so, why? It seems easier to implement with schemas, however I'm not sure if that will actually solve some of the potential longer term performance issues that might come up.

Note that the tables are completely independent - so there are no concerns about needing to joins with other tables.

Also, assume I'm handing any validation that might get me into trouble with malicious and/or unexpected users being able to create database tables.

Comment: So what happens after a user creates a table? Would you allow creating relationships across tables? Would you allow users to create indexes? How would the CRUD processes be built? Any way, if the business requires that the user creates a table, then be it. You best separate such environment from other controlled environments because chances are some on will do something wrong there.

Comment: A user defines a data model in a UI that results in the creation of a table. There is an abstraction layer between them and the database so they can't do any additional work in the DB. The system provides an analytics engine on top of what they build.

Comment: Sounds interesting, I still think that separating this environment is better.

Comment: How about considering `json` `jsonp` or `hstore` data types

Answer (score 1):

From the [Database File Layout](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/storage-file-layout.html) of the manual:

> Each table and index is stored in a separate file.

So, this is the first point to take into account. You should have a filesystem which does a good job with a large number of files in a single directory, unless you use different tablespaces.

Note that you can have different tablespaces even in the same schema or in the same database, so the use of different schemas could by motivated by other reasons, like having tables with the same name (actually, schemas in PostgreSQL are just a way of partitioning the namespace).

For databases, I think the solution with just a database could be good for you, I assume that each database can introduce a non trivial overhead.

Finally: since the system works by using its own catalog, which is a set of relational tables, I suppose you could scale quite well, maybe you will need to add some indexes on the catalog tables, if they are not present.

The last advice: before investing time and resources on the project, *do a simulation* of it, by generating programmatically a thousand tables, filling them with random data, and simulating their use under the hypotheses of the load of your system.